# IOTOP on LXC -> Netlink error

Tags: debian, lxc, proxmox

unfortunately I can not use iotop on proxmox-lxc-container and debian 8 template.

This is the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/sbin/iotop", line 17, in <module>
main()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/iotop/ui.py", line 620, in main
main_loop()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/iotop/ui.py", line 610, in <lambda>
main_loop = lambda: run_iotop(options)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/iotop/ui.py", line 506, in run_iotop
return run_iotop_window(None, options)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/iotop/ui.py", line 498, in run_iotop_window
taskstats_connection = TaskStatsNetlink(options)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/iotop/data.py", line 137, in __init__
self.family_id = controller.get_family_id('TASKSTATS')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/iotop/genetlink.py", line 69, in get_family_id
m = GeNlMessage.recv(self.conn)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/iotop/genetlink.py", line 51, in recv
msg = conn.recv()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/iotop/netlink.py", line 229, in recv
raise err
OSError: Netlink error: No such file or directory (2)
```

Does anybody know how to fix that?

Comment: Why not install and run this on the LXC?